# When the code inside Dispatcher.Invoke is executed?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

In a C# WPF project I have a background thread that needs to refresh some UserControls.
To doing that I used the Dispatcher.Invoke:

```
    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
        // Code
    }
```

But I'm wondering:

- when the code inside the delegate will be executed on the main thread?
- To execute it, a method normally running on main thread could be stopped?
- Could the use of Dispatcher.Invoke lead to race conditions?

Thanks a lot,
Emanuele

Comment: This code is run on the main, UI thread but we'd need to know more about what you are attempting (or what problem you are seeing) to be able to sensibly answer the rest of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when the code inside the delegate will be executed on the main thread?

Delegate will execute on main thread once if all the `operations with priority greater than Normal got a chance to execute`.

> To execute it, a method normally running on main thread could be
>   stopped?

Invoke method make the delegate to execute synchronously on Main thread but if you want to execute it asynchronously, you need to use BeginInvoke. In case some delegate is running on Main thread, your `delegate will get queued and will run once executing operation gets completed`. However, your background thread won't move forward unless delegate gets executed.

> Could the use of Dispatcher.Invoke lead to race conditions?

`No`, it won't since delegate gets queued in Dispatcher Queue.

Comment: I think you meant **a**synchronously in the 2nd part of your sentence.

Comment: @Marcin Deptuła What do you mean? According to edit history "asynchronously" was alwqays there.

Answer (score 0):

1. Exactly when the UI thread is able to switch its execution on `SynchronizationContext.Send` call.
2. When executing it, the method which is normally being run on main thread will finish running (including other pseudo non-finish conditions like `yield` or `await`) and then your function will be ran.
3. No.